# pandas gets stuck when trying to read from bigquery

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I have a fairly large table in big query ( app. 9M rows) and I would like to read it via pandas.

I've tried reading and using the `[pd.read_gbq()][1]` function, which works fine on small tables.

On the large table it gets stuck after 50 secs or so (logs show `elapsed .. 50s`) - without giving an error or anything.

My question is how can I read that table using pd (chunks?). Any conventions on scaling up these bigquery reads will be helpful.

**EDIT / resolution**

adding to Khan's answer, I ended up implementing chunks, writing 500,000 each time to a file, then reading these files to dataframe like so:

```
def download_gbq_table(self):
    if not os.path.exists(self.tmp_dir):
        os.makedirs(self.tmp_dir)
    increment = 100000

    intervals = list(range(0, self.table_size, 100000))
    intervals.append(self.table_size - intervals[len(intervals)-1])

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for offset in intervals:
        query = f"select * from `<table_name>` limit {increment} offset {offset};"
        logger.info(f"running query: {query}")
        start_time = time.time()
        tmp_df = pd.read_gbq(query,
                       project_id=self.connection_parameters['project_id'],
                       private_key=self.connection_parameters['service_account'],
                       dialect='standard'
                        )
        df = pd.concat([df, tmp_df])
        logger.info(f'time took: {str(round(time.time() - start_time, 2))}')
        if len(df) % 500000 == 0:
            df.to_csv(os.path.join(self.tmp_dir, f'df_{str(offset + increment)}.csv'))
            df = pd.DataFrame()

def read_df_from_multi_csv(self):
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.tmp_dir, "df_*"))
    df_list = []

    for f in all_files:
        start_time = time.time()
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(f))
        logger.info(f'time took for reading {f}: {str(round(time.time() - start_time, 2))}')

    return pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas' `read_gbq` function currently does not provide a `chunksize` parameter (even though its opposite `to_gbq` function *does* provide a `chunksize` parameter).

Anyways, you can solve your problem with adding `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to your SQL query read stuff iteratively from BigQuery. Something on the lines of:

```
project_id = "xxxxxxxx"

increment=100000
chunks=[*range(0, 9000000, 100000)]

chunks[-1]+=increment 
intervals=[[chunks[i-1], chunks[i]+1] for i, e in enumerate(chunks) if i > 0]

query_str="select * from `mydataset.mytable` limit {end} offset {start};"

for start, end in intervals:
   query = query_str.format(start=start, end=end)
   df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id)
   #-- do stuff with your df here..
```

Comment: why is this line for: `chunks[-1]+=increment`?

Comment: Just to make sure the range is all-inclusive (and doesn't fall back because of the step size).

Comment: If this helped you, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks :)

Comment: maybe add a line `chunks = list(chunks)` to make sure you can do `chunks[-1]+=increment`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this existed back when the question was originally asked, but now you can use `python-bigquery-sqlalchemy` ([link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy)) to read data from BigQuery, which allows you to use the built-in chunking ability of `pandas.read_sql()`. You just create a SQLAlchemy connection engine using "bigquery://{project-name}" and pass that to `con` in `pandas.read_sql()`.

For example:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import pandas as pd

read_project = "my-cool-project"
query = f"""
    select * from `{read_project}.cool-dataset.cooltable`
"""

bq_engine = create_engine(f"bigquery://{read_project}")
for df in pd.read_sql(query, con=bq_engine, chunksize=100_000):
    # do stuff with df...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way. Set use_bqstorage_api=True. as shown below:

```
df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, dialect="standard", use_bqstorage_api=True)
```

[source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration)